# Two ways to get value of Point object?

Tags: java, point

How come you can get the x and y values from a  java.awt.Point class by using a method and referencing the value?

```
Point p = new Point(10,20);
int x0 = p.getX();
int y0 = p.getY();
int x1 = p.x;
int y1 = p.y;
System.out.println(x0+"=="+x1+"and"+y0+"=="+y1);
```

Did the people who made this class forget to make x and y private?

Comment: A pretty simple object like this which is mainly used in geometry-related stuff is much easier to use with public fields, for example incrementing positions are done with .x+=1. Not every class needs to setters/getters.

Comment: "Did the people who made this class forget to make x and y private?" Yes, basically; remember `java.awt.Point` is one of the oldest Java classes, so it was introduced before all the good encapsulation patterns were really well-known.

Comment: @LouisWasserman i don't believe, encapsulation information hiding are not from 'java era', i think is more what arynaq says

Comment: In Effective Java, Josh Bloch (who wrote many of these APIs originally) states: "Prominent examples include the Point
and Dimension classes in the java.awt package. Rather than examples to be emulated, these classes should be regarded as cautionary tales," and explains why those design decisions are now considered mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#x), these seem to return different types.  `p.x` returns an `int` while `p.getX()` returns a `double`.

The source code of `Point` shows this:

```
public int x;
//...
public double getX() {
    return x;
}
```

So it looks like that's its only purpose.  `getX()` is a more convenient way to get the coordinates as a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
 double x0 = p.getX();

 // getX returns the X coordinate of this Point2D in double precision
```